# EF Core DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am trying to migrate a model using a `DateTime` property to a `DateTimeOffset` property.

When creating the migration, I get the following error:

> The property 'MyProp' is of type 'DateTimeOffset' which is not supported by the current
> database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the
> '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Why can't the C# type `DateTimeOffset` be mapped to the SQL Server Type `datetimeoffset` ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))?

##### Edit: Added Stacktrace

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'MyProp' is of type 'DateTimeOffset' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidatePropertyMapping(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
```

##### Edit added a reproduction

There is a reproduction on [GitHub](https://github.com/eluchsinger/EntityFramework-DateTimeOffsetRepro/tree/main).

Comment: What database provider are you using?

Comment: I just tested creating a simple model including a DateTimeOffset with SQL Server and EF Core 6.  Works fine, including initially using DateTime, and then changing to DateTimeOffset in a migration.

Comment: Is the property using `System.DateTimeOffset` or is it instead a `DateTimeOffset` class/struct from another namespace?

Comment: @Dai SQL Server

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I've added the stacktrace. It comes from the SqlServer Provider.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the property is `System.DateTimeOffset`. I just double checked.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft creating a repro helped me solve the issue. I have included it in the question and written an answer to help others with the same issue. The exception text is a bit misleading, because the issue is not that `DateTimeOffset` is unsupported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is obvious, when taking a closer look at the data model. I have changed the type of the property to be `DateTimeOffset`, but the EF Core type name is fixed using the attribute `[Column("CreateDate", TypeName = "datetime")]`. This creates an ambiguity.

```cs
[Column("CreateDate", TypeName = "datetime")]
[Required]
public DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }
```

Reading the exception message confused me a little, because it states that the Type `DateTimeOffset` is not supported.

```
The property 'CreateDate' could not be mapped because it is of type 'DateTimeOffset', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type.
```